# How can I make a layout like this in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working on an application to book match tickets, I need to make a scheme like this on the ticket booking page. I hope someone can help me

[flutter stadium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Srk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For first use `Stack` widget to position all objects on map stadium.
For second `InteractiveViewer` help you for zoom in\out.
For third `CustomPainter` to design tribune's and others objects.